# What statistical hypothesis should be used in comparing two options?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

Suppose there are two options (A and B). We choose 25 people to judge about these two options. Each person assigns a grade to each option. We want to find if there is any significant difference between the two options? What hypothesis test should be used? 1 t-test, two-sample t-test, or paired t-test?
Should we use paired t-test just we want to evaluate before and after performances? I got confused about paired and two-sample tests.

Comment: Go through your three options and say why they would make sense or why they wouldn’t.

Comment: I think that I should use two-sample t-test because I am comparing two different groups. But, because the same person is evaluating both of the options, it makes me confused. Should I assume the same variance to use each of them?